# How to create a class which holds list of any children of a class?

Tags: java, class, generics, methods, polymorphism

Java doubts:

let's say I have a class named A.
and I have its child classes as A1, A2, A3, etc. as shown below

e.g.

```
Class A 
{

}

Class A1 extends A {
}

Class A2 extends A{}
Class A3 extends A{}
```

Now I have another class which is ListA class. 
this class has an attribute which is basically a list of any children of class A.

```
Class ListA<T> {
List<T> listOfChildren;

ListA(int n) {
//some how instantiate the above list based on the generic type.
}
}
}
```

I have used generic class because I think it is good way to tackle this use case. But any other suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Is this something you're trying to put in the code, or something you're trying to populate at runtime?

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question. Do you want a list that contains any subclass of A ? Then simply List<A> is your solution

Answer (score 0):

Why not use this:

```
List<? extends ClassA> myList=new ArrayList();
myList.add(myClass);//You will receive an error if you add anything that does not extend from ClassA
```

Comment: Does not answer the question of how to fill the list with all of the subclasses of ClassA

Comment: adding to a list is trivial.

Comment: `List<T extends ClassA>` is not valid. You can only use `TypeVariable extends Bound` in the declaration of the type variable; on a variable, you can only use `? extends Bound` (and you can't add anything except `null` to a `List<? extends ClassA>`).

Comment: "and you can't add anything except `null` to a `List<? extends ClassA>`". You can only add something which extends `ClassA` to a `List<? super ClassA>` (directly).